# Flutter throwing error "Text should be not be null"

Tags: flutter, dart

This code reveals that the text is should be not null. How do I solve this problem, given that the code was working perfectly well.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TitleDefault extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  TitleDefault(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      );
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the title value from the place where you are initialising `TitleDefault`

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are passing null value to the Text widget. You should pass a String value for the `title` parameter while initialising `TitleDefault`.

```
TitleDefault("Hello World")
```

Read the [Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/Text.html) widget constructor documentation to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix can be:

```dart
class TitleDefault extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  TitleDefault(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(
        "${title}",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      );
}
```

Where I added quotes for the variable title, with that way, your Text widget will always have a String provided, but the could still be empty.

You may want to check what arguments you are passing to your TitleDefault widget.

Answer (score 0):

The Text widget doesn't accept a null value, sometimes your app passes null values because of different reasons.
There are lots of tricks to avoid this issue, for example, you can check if the value is not null before returning the text:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(
        title ?? "Title is not available",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      );
}
```

Or you can put the title variable into a string and if the title is null the Text widget will show `"null"`

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(
        "$title",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class TitleDefault extends StatelessWidget {
final String title;

  TitleDefault(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(
    title??"",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  );
```

}

Comment: Fix formatting and add some explanation around: why is this answer valid?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their time

Comment: @Brandt read the question first, i fix the code by using ?? condition.. Simple

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @mufazmi ok thanks, i will provide full info about my code next time